# Simplest way to apply CSS background color to nth child 3 to 10

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to apply CSS background color to nth child 3 to 10

```
    <div class="roundperiodbg" id="roundPeriod1" title="PERIOD 1"></div>
    <div class="roundperiodbg" id="roundPeriod2" title="PERIOD 1"></div>

    <div class="roundperiodbg" id="roundPeriod3" title="PERIOD 2"></div>
    <div class="roundperiodbg" id="roundPeriod4" title="PERIOD 2"></div>
    <div class="roundperiodbg" id="roundPeriod5" title="PERIOD 2"></div>
    <div class="roundperiodbg" id="roundPeriod6" title="PERIOD 2"></div>
    <div class="roundperiodbg" id="roundPeriod7" title="PERIOD 2"></div>
    <div class="roundperiodbg" id="roundPeriod8" title="PERIOD 2"></div>
    <div class="roundperiodbg" id="roundPeriod9" title="PERIOD 2"></div>
    <div class="roundperiodbg" id="roundPeriod10" title="PERIOD 2"></div>

    <div class="roundperiodbg" id="roundPeriod11" title="PERIOD 3"></div>
    <div class="roundperiodbg" id="roundPeriod12" title="PERIOD 3"></div>
    <div class="roundperiodbg" id="roundPeriod13" title="PERIOD 3"></div>
    <div class="roundperiodbg" id="roundPeriod14" title="PERIOD 3"></div>
    <div class="roundperiodbg" id="roundPeriod15" title="PERIOD 3"></div>
    <div class="roundperiodbg" id="roundPeriod16" title="PERIOD 3"></div>
    <div class="roundperiodbg" id="roundPeriod17" title="PERIOD 3"></div>
    <div class="roundperiodbg" id="roundPeriod18" title="PERIOD 3"></div>
```

This works but is there any simpler way in CSS?

```
.roundperiodbg:nth-child(3), .roundperiodbg:nth-child(4), ..... .roundperiodbg:nth-child(10) {
        background : green;

}
```

Comment: If you only wanted a CSS answer you shouldn't have tagged your question [jquery]. Just saying.

Comment: @BoltClock If i am not tag the jquery may be still i am not get the right answer. Jquery person also know css 100%

Comment: You can't make that assumption. And like I said, since you're clearly not asking for a jQuery answer, it's simply inappropriate to tag a non-jQuery question with [jquery].

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use two `:nth-child()` selectors to create a range like this:

```
.roundperiodbg:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+10){
     background : green;
}
```

See this **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/yb7j3/)**.

### Explanation:

`:nth-child(n+3)` selects all elements with an index equal or great than 3

```
------
n | i
------
0 | 3
------
1 | 4
------
2 | 5
------
3 | 6
------
..| ..
```

`:nth-child(-n+10)` selects all elements with an index equal or lower than 10

```
------
n | i
------
0 | 10
------
1 | 9
------
2 | 8
------
3 | 7
------
..| 1
```

When you apply both in the same CSS rule the element would have to match both conditions therefore it only applies to elements with index between 3 and 10.

---

Also you can check out [this link](http://nthmaster.com/) for more cool uses of the `:nth-child()` selector. **Thanks @Rajaprabhu**

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just create a new class like:

```
.roundperiodbg-green {
   background: green;
}
```

and apply it to all your divs that need this styling?

Answer (score 0):

Create a container an put all your items in the container. and use below css code:

```
.container>div:nth-child(n+3){
  background : green;
}
```

[Look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YgYxh/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
    .roundperiodbg{ background:#333; height:10px; width:100%; margin:5px;}
    .roundperiodbg:nth-child(n + 4){ background:green;}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code -

```
$('.roundperiodbg:gt(2):lt(10)').css('background','green');
```

In this `:gt(n)` specifies that any element after nth element will be selected, and `lt(n)` specifies any element before nth element will be selected